# Can i play FFXIV with my USA account on the physical EUR version on a NTSC (USA) Ps3?

Tags: ps3, psn, final-fantasy-14

Can i play Final Fantasy XIV with my USA account on the physical EUR version on a NTSC, USA Ps3?

*I already have the digital, downloaded game, and i can already play it with my USA account, plus the game that was downloaded from it.*

But what if i have an physical-European copy of the game, could i still play with it? will be there any issues?

**Edit: I found people asked for something similar on the Internet, but for the Pc version, not for the Ps3 version.**

Comment: IIRC PS3's region lock works on disc-level, while FFXIV's server doesn't care where you are as long as you're connecting to your account, which allows you to choose which server you want to play. On PC version, I created an EU account to play on JP server and it worked fine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**There will be no issues playing a European version of almost any game on an American PlayStation 3, or with a United States account, as PlayStation 3 is (almost entirely) region free, at least, for physical games.**

Since this is common knowledge for me, being a sales assistant in an electronic retailer, I did a quick search for validity. Mostly forums, but forums I trust.

Physical games (in most aspects) have no region locking. But store content does. If you are signed into the US store, you can only access content you have paid for from the US store, and vice versa. So ensure you are using the account you wish to keep all your DLCs and trophys on.

Confirmed [on the Europe forums](http://community.eu.playstation.com/t5/PlayStation-3-Games/Is-the-PS3-Region-Free/td-p/7913384), [at Game Spot](http://www.gamespot.com/forums/playstation-nation-1000002/is-the-ps3-region-free-games-29390229/), [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regional_lockout#Sony), [on the US forums](http://community.us.playstation.com/t5/PlayStation-3/PS3-games-Region-locked-or-free/td-p/5362650), [at the inquirer](http://www.theinquirer.net/inquirer/news/1034649/playstation-region-free) and [on wired.com in words taken from the Sony executives themselves](http://wayback.archive.org/web/20081208071810/http://blog.wired.com/games/2006/09/sony_execs_talk.html?entry_id=1561160).